# Matrix PHP error "Undefined index: directory" after EE update

Tags: matrix, php-errors

does anyone have an idea how I can fix this error message? It flashes up after submitting an entry and stays on screen for only a second or two.

> A PHP Error was encountered
>   Severity: Notice
>   Message: Undefined index: directory
>   Filename: celltypes/file.php
>   Line Number: 395

I'm guessing it's referring to the file fieldtype. But the images and files are OK on the page. And it only occurs on one entry.

Comment: What version of EE and Matrix are you using? Please  edit your original question with to add those details. Also, did you recently perform an EE update by chance?

Comment: EE  v2.7.2 + Matrix 2.5.8. Yes, I've just upgraded the system. The guys at P and T, have helped with a Matrix problem already. Maybe I should get back to them?

Comment: In general the policy on Stack Exchange is for questions about PHP errors to be directed to the add-on developer. But I can tell you I saw this error recently myself so will post it below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recently saw this myself when updating an older site to the latest EE and Matrix. I believe it's because older versions of EE File feildtype did not allow to limit uploads to a specific directory. This corresponds to the "Allowed file upload directories" select menu on the File column in your Matrix custom field.

Just edit your Matrix custom field, re-saving the custom field settings and you should be good.

Comment: Perfect thanks. I had no idea it was Matrix causing the error.

Comment: Glad that worked. For future reference, the way to tell that it was Matrix-related is that the error is in celltypes/file.php which is part of Matrix. When you see an error like that you can use your text editor to locate the given file and it'll help you start to track down the problem.